# How do I choose $\delta$ in the $\epsilon-\delta$ proofs of limits.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

While I understand how $\delta$ is chosen when a funtion is nice and easy, linear function. But I'm having trouble understanding how the $\delta$ is selected for quadratic function or rational functions.

For instance,

I have to prove that, $\lim\limits_{x \to 2} \dfrac{x^3-4}{x^2+1} = \dfrac{4}{5}$

So let $f(x)$ be the given function,

Fixing an $\epsilon>0$, and simplifying $|f(x)- 4/5|$ I get,

$\left| f(x)- \dfrac{4}{5} \right| = \dfrac{|5x^3 +6x+12|}{5(x^2+1)} \cdot |x-2| $

Now I understand I need to get rid of everything except $|x-2|$ possibly by replacing the entire thing by a number.

But I have no clue as to how you choose this number. What should be my *thought process* now?

Thanks!

Comment: You can make a violent bound by restricting 1 < x < 3,  and dropping the x^2 in the denominator.  What will you see?

Comment: Well as $x$ is close to $2$ we might as well assume $1 < x < 3$ so $\frac {23}{50} < \dfrac{|5x^3 +6x+12|}{5(x^2+1)}< \frac {165}{2}$ so let $\delta = \frac 2{165} \epsilon$.  It's crude and inefficient but it definitely works. [I'm of the opinion accuracy in delta epsilon proofs is a wast of time. If you can get away with letting $\delta = \frac 1{googol} \epsilon$ and it works.... why not?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are a gambler you can  pick $\delta = 10^{-100}$ and hope it works.

If $|x - 2| < 10^{-100}$  then $2- 10^{-100} < x < 2 + 10^{-100}$ and therefore:

$\left| f(x)- \dfrac{4}{5} \right| = \dfrac{|5x^3 +6x+12|}{5(x^2+1)} \cdot |x-2| <  \dfrac{|5(2+10^{-100})^3 +6(2+10^{-100})+12|}{5((2-10^{-100})^2+1)} \cdot 10^{-100} =$

$\frac {(5*8 + 6*2 + 12) + (3*5*2^2*10^{-100} + 3*5*2*10^{-200} + 5*10^{-300} + 6*10^{-100})}{(5*4 + 1) +(- 5*4*10^{-100} + 5*10^{-100})}10^{-100} <$

$\frac {(5*8 + 6*2 + 12) + 1}{(5*4 + 1) -1}10^{-100}=\frac {63}{20}10^{-100}=\frac {63}{2*10^{101}}$

Which is less than $\epsilon$ if $\epsilon \ge \frac {63}{2*10^{101}}$

.....

But there's a reason we don't let gamblers be mathematicians.

We need this to find a $\delta$ based on $\epsilon$ that will work for all our $\epsilon$s.  even the $\epsilon < \frac {63}{2*10^{101}}$.

Okay, Let $\delta = 10^{-100}$ if $\epsilon \ge \frac {63}{2*10^{101}}$ but let $\delta = k\epsilon$ if $\epsilon < \frac {63}{2*10^{101}}$

In other words.  Let $\delta = \min(10^{-100}, k\epsilon)$.

We get a similar result:

$\left| f(x)- \dfrac{4}{5} \right| = \dfrac{|5x^3 +6x+12|}{5(x^2+1)} \cdot |x-2| <  \dfrac{|5(2+10^{-100})^3 +6(2+10^{-100})+12|}{5((2-10^{-100})^2+1)} \cdot k\epsilon =$

$< \frac {63}{20}k\epsilon$

And that is less then $\epsilon$ if $k = \frac {20}{63}$.  So that is an acceptable value for $\delta$.  Let $\delta = \min (10^{-100}, \frac {63}{20}\epsilon)$.

.....

Okay, why did I post such a *ridiculous* answer?

My point is, if you can find something nice and linear that's great but if not.. you are allowed to force things to be small enough to work.  It doesn't have to be a close and efficient $\delta$.  It can be *ANY* $\delta$.  Even a $\delta$ as ridiculous as the one I chose.

You won't have to pick something that ridiculously small.  We could simply pick $\delta = \min (2, k\epsilon)$ and get that:

$\left| f(x)- \dfrac{4}{5} \right| = \dfrac{|5x^3 +6x+12|}{5(x^2+1)} \cdot |x-2| <  \dfrac{|5(2+2)^3 +6(2+2)+12|}{5((2-2)^2+1)} \cdot k\epsilon =356k\epsilon $

So $\delta = \min(2, \frac 1{356}\epsilon)$ will do.

Comment: Thank you for this answer :) I have a feeling Maths is going to be a lot fun.

Answer (score 2):

A convenient way would be to require $\delta<1$, so that we can take 
$$
1<x<3
$$
Then, the smallest $x^2+1$ can be is $2$ and the largest the increasing $5x^3+6x+12$ can be is $5(3)^3+6\cdot 3+12=165$, so 
$$
\frac{5x^3+6x+12}{5(x^2+1)}\leq \frac{165}{10}=16.5
$$
now you can take 
$$
\delta=\frac12\min \{ 1,\frac{\epsilon}{16.5} \}
$$

Note, there is no canonical choice for $\delta>0$, meaning lots of choices will work.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I have a few questions, first off why did you take $\delta <1$, this thing right here really confuses me. Why not take any other inequality, let's say $0.7<\delta<5$ or something. Second off, did you mean, take $\delta < \mathrm{min}\{1, \frac{\epsilon}{16.5} \}$. Because you you did say, you required $\delta < 1$ earlier.

Comment: @William you can take $\delta<5$ if you would like, it will just change the number. The point is we really only care about $\delta$ small, since we care about points near $1$. Once we restrict delta in this way bounding that quantity becomes easier. That's a good point, I will edit to take $\frac{1}{2}$ of the minimum :)

Comment: @William "Why pick $\delta<1$?" is a _really_ common objection many people have when they first encounter $\epsilon$-$\delta$. As qbert said, there is no real significance to $1$ here (although for some functions, like $\frac1x$, it _does_ matter what you pick). The point is that continuity only really cares about small $\delta$ and small $\epsilon$. But if you don't limit $\delta$, then your final expression for $\delta$ will have to consider that some devil's advocate may pick out a huge value for $\epsilon$ instead, and the resulting expression for $\delta$ will be unnecessarily complicated

Comment: @Arthur thank you, but I think the example I gave, $0.7<\delta < 5$ should be wrong because of the lower bound I put on $\delta$ ...am I right? Unless I'm over thinking, $\delta > A$, delta can't be chosen this way...it must be less than or equal $A$.

Comment: @William You are right. For the smallest of $\epsilon$ we will need the smallest of $\delta$, so bounding $\delta$ away from $0$ with something like $\delta>0.7$ is generally a bad idea.

Comment: You can't assume $\delta > anything$ as the point is to get $x$ close to $2$.  But you can assume $\delta < anything \ positive$.  In this case you probably want $\delta < 2$ so we can assume $x$ is positive.  $\delta < 1$ made the math easy.  That's all.  If we wanted accuracy we could have assumed $\delta < 0.01$ and $1.99 < x < 2.01$ and $ \frac {5(1.99)^3 + 6(1.99) + 12}{5((2.01)^2 +1)}< \dfrac{|5x^3 +6x+12|}{5(x^2+1)}< \frac {5(2.01)^3 + 6(2.01) + 12}{5((1.99)^2 +1)}$ and let $\delta =\frac{5((1.99)^2 +1)} {5(2.01)^3 + 6(2.01) + 12}\epsilon$ .  But that makes the math hard.

Answer (score 2):

Your thought process might be something like

I know I can make the $|x-2|$ small just by a direct choice of $\delta$. But that other factor might make the right side big. Can I bound the first factor on the right, so that I can be sure it won't do too much damage? Well, it's a fraction. Fractions are large when their denominators are small. The denominator of the factor is always at least $5$, so the fraction is no larger than $1/5$ of the numerator. Now the numerator of the fraction is an increasing function near $x=2$, so as long as $x < 10$ the numerator will be less than $6000$. (I could get a much better bound than that with a smaller $x$ and more arithmetic, but why bother?)

Now I know that when $x < 10$ the right side is  bounded by $(6000/5)|x-2|$. That tells me that as long as $\delta < 10$ and $\delta < (5/6000)\epsilon$ I'll have the bound I need on the value of the function.